# Are either Perfume or Hannibal Lecter Franchise inspired by each others' source materials?

Tags: reference, hannibal, perfume

I just recently watched the German TV series, *[Perfume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfume_(TV_series))* released and distributed internationally through Netflix.

[image: Perfume TV series]

The series is inspired by **the 1985 historical fantasy** [novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfume_(novel)), *Perfume: The Story of a Murderer* by Patrick Süskind and the 2006 film of the same name, but also includes characters who become obsessed with the fantasy novel, as it relates to a group of friends from boarding school and a series of murders committed throughout the years, **in which there are experiments conducted and used to manipulate others through capturing human scents...**

[image: Hannibal TV series]

The cannibalistic serial killer Hannibal Lecter is first introduced in the **1981 crime thriller**, [Red Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dragon_(novel)) by Thomas Harris. Over the course of next couple of novels, most noticeably the third in the series titular-titled *Hannibal* novel, it becomes apparent that Hannibal has many skills from being an adept psychoanalysis, amazing cook, has great taste, **and also has a six sense for smells to the point of insinuating something [near](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/quora/whats-the-significance-of_b_11591200.html) supernatural.**

Now Hannibal's ability to smell comes off as something more well-rounded apart of whom he is, instead of it being the primary fixation of Thomas Harris' work, where clearly all things *Perfume-related* delve more into the notion of that particular sense, the art & chemistry of perfumery, and how it can be used.

At any rate, I find the connection in subject matter and timing of written source materials interesting and was wondering **if either was in any way influential to the other?**

Comment: "Self-titled" ?